# Help with Combinatorial argument ${2n\choose {2}} = 2{n\choose 2} + n^2$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

Show by a Combinatorics argument
$${2n\choose {2}} = 2{n\choose 2} + n^2$$

I guess I'm having trouble with the "Combinatorial argument" part. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Have you tried anything towards solving the problem?

Comment: Hint: On the left, you have $2n$ objects, and you must choose $2$ of them. Splitting the $2n$ objects into two piles of $n$, how else can you think about choosing $2$?

Comment: Somewhat. I suppose I'm generally not all too comfortable with Combinatorial style proofs. My first intuition was to begin with saying something tantamount to "suppose we have a committee of $2n$ people. But I'm not sure what to do from there.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have $2n$ flowers, number of ways to choose 2 of them is ${2n \choose 2}$ hence the left part of your equation

How else can we count them? we can part them in two n-groups of flowers, so we can choose 2 from the first group by ${n \choose 2}$ ways or 2 from the second group by ${n \choose 2}$ ways. Or we can choose one from the first group (n ways) and one from the second (again n ways) which gives us $n^2$ ways

Adding these together gives us 2${n \choose 2}$ + $n^2$ which is the right part of your equation

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\binom {2n}2$ counts ways to select $2$ items from a collection of $2n$ items

Hint: $2\binom n2+n^2 = \binom 2 1\binom n 2+\binom n1\binom n1$.  What might this count?